# Changed datagridview cell backgroung color

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I try: `dataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;` and it works fine but in case i am add item to my `datagridview` i don't know which Row number i am working with.

this is how i am adding items to my datagridview:

```
    public void addToDataGridView()
    {
        dataGridView.Rows.Add( "test1", fileName, fileSize, DateTime.Now, "myStatus");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dataGridView.Rows.Add` method gives you the index of the added row.

```
public void addToDataGridView()
{
    int index = dataGridView.Rows.Add("test1", fileName, fileSize, DateTime.Now, "myStatus");
    dataGridView.Rows(index).Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one way to do this:

1. If you need to change color for entire column:

   ```
   DGV.Columns[ColumnIndexToColor].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.AliceBlue;
   ```
2. If you need to change color based on some condition and your DGV is bound, you can use DataBindingComplete event

   ```
   private void DGV_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
   {
     if(DGV.Rows.Count>0 && DGV.Columns.Count>0)
     {
       foreach (DataGridViewRow r in DGV.Rows)
       {
         if(condition)
         {
           DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = r.Cells[ColumnIndexToColor];
           cell.Style.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. If you need to change color based on some condition and your DGV is not bound: when you add row to DGV as in answer by @Chris

Comment: That's interesting, thanks...you say that for example each time new item added to my DGV i can register to this event and act according my condition ?

Comment: DataGridViewBindingComplete is called if you have some DataSource bound to your DataGridView. If you don't, and you want to change color when adding rows, there is RowsAdded event. There is also CellFormatting event that can be used for setting color (it sometimes blinks a little): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

if you are using dataGridView.Rows.Add(), you are adding row to end of dgw => its index will be dataGridView.Rows.Count - 1

EDIT:
Solution of Chris is much better than using dataGridView.Rows.Count - 1

You can choose other solution - you create DataGridViewRow in which you can set style etc. and then simply add it to dgw.